# Where could an aspiring follower of Urgathoa (may she stay forever gluttonous) find a complete list of diseases?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, disease, antipaladin

As an aspiring antipaladin of Urgathoa, I noticed the [Plague Bringer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/antipaladin/#TOC-Plague-Bringer-Ex-) ability that allows me to contract diseases without suffering any ill effects, thus enabling me to carry and spread disease in the name of my goddess with ease.

However, what I had a bit more difficulty finding is a complete list of all diseases (because if I'm going to collect some, might as well collect them all right?). [Here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/diseases/diseases-paizo-inc/) I found a list of a good number of diseases, but it doesn't have Mummy Rot among others.

So is there a resource that has all the different diseases aggregated together?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[That](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/diseases/diseases-paizo-inc/) is a comprehensive list of diseases. Mummy Rot is not there because it is primarily a curse (it can be found [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/curses/)), being a disease is a minor part of it (removing a curse requires magic, a disease doesn't).

However, a [complete list of diseases specific to Golarion](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Diseases_of_Golarion) can be found on Pathfinder Wiki. A lot of references can be found in there to find the source of those diseases, but normally are from adventure paths and modules.

Comment: remove disease and remove curse are both 3rd level spells

Comment: I could swear remove disease was 2nd. But i was thinking about blindness and remove blindness.

Comment: It is 2nd for one cleric domain, actually, but I confirm it to be generally 3rd.

Comment: That must be what i was thinking then. Anyway, the point is that a curse is a more serious problem than a disease. Of course, this depends on which disease and curse we are talking about.